# ReplaceAll with named pattern

Tags: replacement, pattern-matching

If `k` is unassigned, this yields `{a, b, c}`:

```
a f[1] + b f[2] + c f[3] /. f[k_] -> UnitVector[3, k]
```

However, if I set `k = 1`, it yields `{a+b+c, 0, 0}`. Why does it not recognize `k` as a pattern, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Use `RuleDelayed[]` (`:>`) and not `Rule[]` (`->`).